# Propositional Logic in Prolog - Incorrect Representations

Tags: prolog, logic, logical-operators, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

There are certain premises which I am unable to represent correctly in prolog, which are as follows:

1. "I can only sleep well if I am neither in a noisy environment nor have caffeine before bedtime."

   `SleepWell <-> (-Noisy & -Caffeine)`
2. "When I drive or take the subway to work, I am not stuck in traffic."

   `(GoToWork) & (GoByDrive | GoBySubway) -> -StuckInTraffic`
3. "I cannot access the internet except through Wi-Fi, Ethernet, or mobile data."

   `(Internet | Ethernet | MobileData) -> Internet`
4. "If I forget my umbrella when I'm not at home and not wearing my raincoat, I get wet."

   `(ForgetUmbrella & -Home & -Raincoat) -> GetWet`
5. "If it snows, I don't go skiing, and it is never windy except when it's snows."

   `Snows -> -Skiing & (Snows -> Windy)`
6. "When I play basketball, I wear my sneakers; otherwise, I never wear it."

   `PlayBasketBall <-> WearSneakers`
7. "If I'm not at home during a thunderstorm and can't find shelter, I get soaked."

   `(-Home & ThunderStorm & -Shelter) -> Soaked`
8. "I will get wet unless I go to city by car."

   `(GoToCity & GoByCar) -> -Wet`

These premises are part of exercises (with distinct goals) I am currently practicing with Prolog. However, while I have been able to figure out the rest, these above mentioned premises are being shown as incorrect representations.

Comment: What do you mean by "represent correctly in Prolog"?

Comment: I would like to apologise if I have not provided it clearly, we are using prolog for propositional logic. Here's some context:
(a) -> (if...then...)
(b) <-> (if..and..only...if)
(c)  - (negation) ¬
(d) & (conjuction - AND) ∧
(e) | (disjunction - OR) ∨

For instance, I can rewrite it as:

"I can only sleep well if I am neither in a noisy environment nor have caffeine before bedtime."

SleepWell ↔ ¬(Noisy ∨ Caffeine)

Comment: I follow that part of it, but what do you need as the result? Do you know that `,` is conjunction, `;` is disjunction, `->` is if...then... in Prolog or are you stuck on something else about them? Is `playBasketBall -> wearSneakers.` a valid answer? Or more explicitly `playBasketBall -> wearSneakers ; dontWearSneakers.`?